# Custom xib not sized correctly inside superview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4, swift5

I have a bit of a complicated UI structure.

I have a collection view. For the collection view's cells, I have a custom xib. Inside that custom xib, I load another custom xib into a UIView.

Here is a picture of my collection view cell's custom xib:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQLpj.png

I have also highlighted the UIView (Video Container View) that I load another xib into. Here is what that xib looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpSi0.png

With the collection view, I do some custom resizing of the cells by making the view 16:9 ratio:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    // Get the width of the screen
    let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width

    let imageWidth = width
    let imageHeight = imageWidth / (16 / 9)
    
    self.postMediaHeight = imageHeight
    
    return CGSize(width: imageWidth, height: imageHeight)
}
```

My `PostMediaCollectionViewCell` class looks like this:

```
class PostMediaCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var container: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var moreView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var moreViewLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var videoContainerView: VideoContainerView!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
    
    func initialize() {
        //
    }
}
```

And my `VideoContainerView` class looks like this:

```
class VideoContainerView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var rootView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var videoView: VideoView!
    @IBOutlet weak var playIconContainer: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var timeContainer: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel!
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        initialize()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        initialize()
    }
    
    func initialize() {
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("VideoContainerView", owner: self, options: nil)
        rootView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(rootView)

        rootView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        rootView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        rootView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        rootView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    }

}
```

But when I run the simulator, the `VideoContainerView` doesn't seem to fit the superview's (the cell's) constraints/frame, as you can see in the screenshot below. First, there's a white space above the video, and second, the video's resolution is stretch past the container.

[image]

**One interesting thing I noticed is that if I scroll down past the cell and then scroll back up, it shows the video perfectly.**

What am I doing wrong, and what am I missing here?

## Update

I just printed out the bounds of a number of views and noticed that the `videoView` bounds are different from its parents bounds:

```
rootview bounds:  (0.0, 0.0, 661.0, 410.0)
videoview bounds:  (0.0, 0.0, 654.0, 593.0)
```

What should I do here?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `constraints` while adding `rootView` as subview of `VideoContainerView`. In `initialize` add following constraints.

```
func initialize() {
    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("VideoContainerView", owner: self, options: nil)
    rootView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    addSubview(rootView)

    rootView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    rootView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
    rootView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    rootView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

Comment: Getting strange behaviour, might be unrelated to your answer. At first, when I tried your solution, I thought it didn't work because the `VideoContainerView` was still not being displayed correctly. But when I scrolled down the page and then back up, the `VideoContainerView` displayed correctly. What could the cause of this be? (my page is a table view, with its cells holding the collection view in my post)

Comment: Need more details to answer that. Just a quick one, try collectionViewCell fixed width and height and see if it works.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

container is the main view of **VideoContainerView**
Change initialize method code as below and try to run your code

```
func initialize() {
   let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("VideoContainerView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! UIView
   addSubview(view)
   container.frame = self.bounds
   container.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth,.flexibleHeight]        
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not seem to help.